# Problems running Ruby code, Unexpected tIDENTIFIER and tCONSTANT cannot find bug

Tags: ruby

I get these errors :

```
    36.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        if door2 == "yes" || door2 == "Yes"
                        ^
ex36.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
        if door2 == "yes" || door2 == "Yes"
                                          ^
ex36.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        elsif door2 == "no" || door2 == "No"
                          ^
ex36.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
        elsif door2 == "no" || door2 == "No"
                                           ^
ex36.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
            puts "Well, you tried."
                      ^
ex36.rb:48: dynamic constant assignment
            puts "Well, you tried."
                       ^
ex36.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
            puts "Well, you tried."
                                 ^
ex36.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
            puts "You are now dead of thirst. Good night!"
                     ^
ex36.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
            puts "I don\'t understand you, sorry."
                   ^
ex36.rb:51: unterminated string meets end of file
```

when running this code :

```
    def start 
    puts "There is two doors for you to choose."
    puts "Do you pick door number one or door number two?"
    print ">> "
    door = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if door == 'one' || door == '1'
        door_one
    elsif door == 'two' || door == '2'
        door_two
    else
        puts "A dark mist is sprayed into the air."
        puts "Your body starts swelling up."
        puts "You explode and are now dead. Good job!"
        puts "\nWould you like to restart?"

        print ">> "
        restart = $stdin.gets.chomp
        if restart == "yes" || restart == "Yes"
            puts "OK\n"
            start
        else
            puts "OK, have a nice day."
        end
    end
end

def door_one
    puts "You see 5 bee hives with bees swarming around them. What do you do?"
    print ">> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if choice == "Attack!"
        puts "You suffer from 500 bee stings."
        puts "Due to a combination of the venom, the stress your body is taking and your severe bee allergy, you die."
    elsif choice == "Go back through the door"
        puts "The door is locked and the bees attack you. You\'re dead now. Good night!"
    elsif choice == "Befriend them" || choice == "Befriend the bees"
        puts "The bees let you pass."
        puts "You now see another door."
        puts "Do you go through it?
        print ">> "
        door2 = $stdin.gets.chomp

        if door2 == "yes" || door2 == "Yes"
            door_two
        elsif door2 == "no" || door2 == "No"
            puts "Well, you tried."
            puts "You are now dead of thirst. Good night!"
        else
            puts "I don\'t understand you, sorry."
            door_one
        end
    else
        puts "You confuse me."
        door_one
    end
end

def door_two
    puts "You are now standing in front of a giant abyss. What do you do?"

    print ">> "
    choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

    if choice == "Jump in." || choice == "Jump" || choice == "Jump." || choice == "Jump in"
        puts "You jump in, after a while you start seeing light."
        puts "You start feeling very sleepy and decide you are going to take a nap."
        puts "You never wake up. Good night!"
    elsif choice == "Sit" || choice == "Sit down" || choice == "Sit." || choice == "Sit down."
        puts "Your body starts to rot, Your bones can no longer move."
        puts "You have been paralyzed."
        puts "You are dead."
    else 
        puts "You confuse me."
        door_two
    end
end

start
```

Any help would be appreciated, I know that is a lot of errors but I have been trying to figure them out for days.

I am currently writing Exercise 36 of Learn Ruby The Hard Way and I really want to move on to Learn C The Hard Way or Eloquent Ruby

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is copy and pasted, you're missing a close double quotes in the 13th line of the `door_one` method: `puts "Do you go through it?`. The error you're seeing would be expected if that typo is there. Whenever I see that error, I immediately start looking for a missing `'`, `"`, `]`, `}`, `)`, or `end`.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott Schupbach you have fixed all of the errors.

Comment: You should really get yourself a proper editor with good syntax highlighting. Even StackOverflow's crappy syntax highlighting makes the error blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 2):

### Fixing Your Precedence Issue

> if door2 == "yes" || door2 == "Yes"

While `||` and `or` have roughly equivalent semantics, they have a different precedence. You either need to separate your expressions with parentheses, or use the lower-precence `or` operator instead. For example:

```
# Separate your expressions.
if (door2 == "yes") || (door2 == "Yes")

# Use a lower-precedence operator.
if door2 == "yes" or door2 == "Yes"
```

You'll need to do this throughout your codebase.

### Use a Regular Expression Instead

More idiomatically, you can simply search for a case-insentive regular expression anchored to the start of your response string. While it doesn't really address your problem directly, it neatly sidesteps the issue of operator precedence in your current if-statement while also providing a bit more flexibility. For example:

```
if door2 =~ /\Ay(?:es)?/i
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, after learning ruby I have also been planning to learn regex when zed shaw's book comes out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Although I still get many errors like unexpected tCONSTANT expecting keyword_end and same thing with tIDENTIFIER

Comment: I don't understand, as `==` has higher precedence than `||`.